# Send Email using SMTP and php

Tags: php, smtp

I have developed hotspot system using php language.
I want to allow user to send email from my system.
user will configure email to send email
user must insert his (smtp server, smtp username , smtp password , from email)
and if his entry was correct he can send email to any one 
I used this code but it not worked

```
        include 'mails/class.phpmailer.php';
        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
       $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth =false;
       $mail->Host = 'ssl://smtps.gmail.com';
       $mail->Port = 465;
       $mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com';
       $mail->Password = 'johnsmith';
       $mail->SetFrom('starking123eng@gmail.com', 'Benim Adım');
       $mail->AddAddress("example2@gmail.com", 'Alıcının Adı');
         $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
       $mail->Subject = 'Mail Başlığı';
        $msg='sdljfkjsd';

        $mail->MsgHTML($msg);
        $mail->Send();
```

Comment: Could you explain how it didn't work? What was the error etc?

Comment: there is nor error but the mail not sent

Comment: Please post relevant error messages and any relevant data - e.g. what are the values of `$email`, `$msg5` and `$row`?

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Please try to check this out you should configure your gmail smtp first check this out:
[link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en)

Then you can change the $mail->SetFrom('starking123eng@gmail.com', 'Benim 
Adım'); to $mail->SetFrom($emailOfUser, $nameOfUser);